# Is there a Linux tool that can automatically syncronise (monitor) two folders on local drives with different filesystems?

Tags: ext4, ntfs, synchronization

I have Linux computer with external NTFS drive. I need one of the directories of the internal drive (ext4) being automatically syncronised with an external drive directory.

The complication stems from the combination of words `automatically` and `NTFS` (I believe I know how to achieve that goal in case of two ext4 drives; manual syncronisation of ext4 and NTFS is not a big deal either).

P. S. The directories in sync are supposed to contain something like ten thousands of files (that being said it is only a few files that are being changed per, say, minute, so a lot of stuff to watch, but not that much to update).

Comment: `rsync` doesn't care about filesystems, so the existing tools should work.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov You are right, but the problem is how to monitor the NTFS directory (as far as I understand inotify does not work with NTFS, so it is unclear what should trigger rsync run).

Comment: Have you tried? It's now the second false assumption. `inotifywait` works just fine with ntfs-3g.